# Optional parameter on Angular Directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I created a directive on Angular that receives 5 parameters and one of them is an optional array. The way I'm trying to deal with it is like follows:

```
app.directive('fooDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {
            param1: '=',
            param2: '=' // optional array
        },
        template: //...
                "<div ng-class='defineClass()'> Message </div>"
                  //...
        controller: function($scope) {

             if (typeof $scope.param2 === 'undefined')
                  $scope.param2 = [];

             console.log($scope.param2);

             $scope.defineClass = function() {
                  if ($scope.param2.length == 0) return 'gray-text';
                  return 'red-text';
             };

             // ......
         }
    }
});
```

At some point in my code I check for the `.length` of `param2` and if it is undefined it throws a lot of errors. What is driving me nuts is that the `console.log()` you can see there outputs a `[]`, indicating that the `.length` of my param should be 0 and the errors on the console are shown after the output of the console.log().

So I guess I am missing something about either the way Angular binds the scopes or the flow that the directive is constructed. I have tried verifing my param on both `link` and `compile` phases and got the same problem.

So, what am I missing here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add the `?` to make it optional (like `param2: '=?'`)

Comment: *At some point in my code I check for the .length of param2*: where is that code?

Comment: Here are you code that check: if ($scope.param2.length == 0)

Comment: JB Nizet I update it with a kinda of example. ryanyuyu it did work, can't believe it was that simple... Can you explain why doing like I was doing didn't work?
Thanks

Answer (score 53, accepted):

From the [angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-) (see the section for `scope` bi-directional binding):

> `=` or `=attr` - set up bi-directional binding between a local scope property and the parent scope property of name defined via the value of the attr attribute....
> If the parent scope property doesn't exist, it will throw a NON_ASSIGNABLE_MODEL_EXPRESSION exception. You can avoid this behavior using `=?` or `=?attr` in order to flag the property as optional.

So the solution to make the parameter optional is to change the binding to be an optional two-way binding with the additional `?`.

```
...
scope: {
    param1: '=',
    param2: '=?' // notice the ? makes this parameter optional.
},
...
```